# Retain Original Value/State of "GENERATED AS IDENTITY" Column

Tags: oracle

I have a table that has a unique increment column created using command "GENERATED AS IDENTITY" and the data type is NUMBER(20,0).
Now, the dev want to change the data type to NUMBER(19,0). Since there are hundreds of tables and millions of data, creating a new set of tables just for one column change is not ideal.
So, I manage to create a workflow as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE my_schema.my_table 
ADD REC_ID_TEMP NUMBER(19,0);

UPDATE my_schema.my_table 
SET REC_ID_TEMP = REC_ID;

ALTER TABLE my_schema.my_table 
DROP COLUMN REC_ID;

ALTER TABLE my_schema.my_table 
ADD REC_ID NUMBER(19,0) GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY;

UPDATE my_schema.my_table 
SET REC_ID = REC_ID_TEMP;

ALTER TABLE my_schema.my_table
MODIFY REC_ID NUMBER(19,0) GENERATED AS IDENTITY MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1515 //Must start with the last REC_ID value +1// CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOKEEP  NOSCALE NOT NULL ENABLE;
```

This is the best way possible that I can think of with this peanut size brain of mine.
This way, I can make sure that the REC_ID is the exact same as before I change the data type.
But, the problem is, if you read my the last line of my script, I have to check the last REC_ID for the hundreds of table before I can run the last script. I need help to figure out a way that I can retain the original state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `START WITH LIMIT VALUE` clause instead of specifying a number. [From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/ALTER-TABLE.html#GUID-552E7373-BF93-477D-9DA3-B2C9386F2877__CJABEJEF):

> START WITH LIMIT VALUE, which is specific to identity_options, can only be used with ALTER TABLE MODIFY. If you specify START WITH LIMIT VALUE, then Oracle Database locks the table and finds the maximum identity column value in the table (for increasing sequences) or the minimum identity column value (for decreasing sequences) and assigns the value as the sequence generator's high water mark. The next value returned by the sequence generator will be the high water mark + INCREMENT BY integer for increasing sequences, or the high water mark - INCREMENT BY integer for decreasing sequences.

Comment: Thank you for this! I find that this really help a lot with my work.

Answer (score 0):

A little automation can make this as easily as calling a procedure per table, eg

```
SQL>
SQL> create table t1 as select * from scott.emp;

Table created.

SQL> create table t2 as select *  from dba_objects;

Table created.

SQL> create table t3 as select *  from dba_procedures;

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> alter table t1 add rec_id number(20) generated by default as identity start with 100000;

Table altered.

SQL> alter table t2 add rec_id number(20) generated by default as identity start with 100000;

Table altered.

SQL> alter table t3 add rec_id number(20) generated by default as identity start with 100000;

Table altered.

SQL>
SQL> update t1 set rec_id = rownum;

14 rows updated.

SQL> update t2 set rec_id = rownum;

81264 rows updated.

SQL> update t3 set rec_id = rownum;

37644 rows updated.

SQL>
SQL> alter table t1 add primary key ( rec_id);

Table altered.

SQL> alter table t2 add primary key ( rec_id);

Table altered.

SQL> alter table t3 add primary key ( rec_id);

Table altered.

SQL>
SQL> alter table t1 modify rec_id number(20) generated always as identity start with 100000;

Table altered.

SQL> alter table t2 modify rec_id number(20) generated always as identity start with 100000;

Table altered.

SQL> alter table t3 modify rec_id number(20) generated always as identity start with 100000;

Table altered.

SQL>
SQL> create or replace
  2  procedure fix_up_my_recid(p_table varchar2) is
  3  begin
  4    execute immediate 'alter table '||p_table||' add tmp$rec_id number(19,0)';
  5
  6    execute immediate 'update '||p_table||' set tmp$rec_id = rec_id';
  7
  8    execute immediate 'alter table '||p_table||' set unused column rec_id';
  9
 10    execute immediate 'alter table '||p_table||' add rec_id number(19,0) generated by default as identity';
 11
 12    execute immediate 'update '||p_table||' set rec_id = tmp$rec_id';
 13
 14    execute immediate 'alter table '||p_table||' set unused column tmp$rec_id';
 15
 16    execute immediate 'alter table '||p_table||' move online';
 17
 18    execute immediate 'alter table '||p_table||' modify rec_id number(19,0) generated always as identity start with limit value';
 19
 20  end;
 21  /

Procedure created.

SQL> sho err
No errors.
SQL>
SQL>
SQL>
SQL> desc t1
 Name                                                                    Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------- -------- ------------------------------------------------
 EMPNO                                                                   NOT NULL NUMBER(4)
 ENAME                                                                            VARCHAR2(10)
 JOB                                                                              VARCHAR2(9)
 MGR                                                                              NUMBER(4)
 HIREDATE                                                                         DATE
 SAL                                                                              NUMBER(7,2)
 COMM                                                                             NUMBER(7,2)
 DEPTNO                                                                           NUMBER(2)
 REC_ID                                                                  NOT NULL NUMBER(20)

SQL> exec fix_up_my_recid('T1')

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec fix_up_my_recid('T2')

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec fix_up_my_recid('T3')

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> desc t1
 Name                                                                    Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------- -------- ------------------------------------------------
 EMPNO                                                                   NOT NULL NUMBER(4)
 ENAME                                                                            VARCHAR2(10)
 JOB                                                                              VARCHAR2(9)
 MGR                                                                              NUMBER(4)
 HIREDATE                                                                         DATE
 SAL                                                                              NUMBER(7,2)
 COMM                                                                             NUMBER(7,2)
 DEPTNO                                                                           NUMBER(2)
 REC_ID                                                                  NOT NULL NUMBER(19)

SQL>
SQL>
SQL>
SQL>
SQL> desc t2
 Name                                                                    Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------- -------- ------------------------------------------------
 OWNER                                                                            VARCHAR2(128)
 OBJECT_NAME                                                                      VARCHAR2(128)
 SUBOBJECT_NAME                                                                   VARCHAR2(128)
 OBJECT_ID                                                                        NUMBER
 DATA_OBJECT_ID                                                                   NUMBER
 OBJECT_TYPE                                                                      VARCHAR2(23)
 CREATED                                                                          DATE
 LAST_DDL_TIME                                                                    DATE
 TIMESTAMP                                                                        VARCHAR2(19)
 STATUS                                                                           VARCHAR2(7)
 TEMPORARY                                                                        VARCHAR2(1)
 GENERATED                                                                        VARCHAR2(1)
 SECONDARY                                                                        VARCHAR2(1)
 NAMESPACE                                                                        NUMBER
 EDITION_NAME                                                                     VARCHAR2(128)
 SHARING                                                                          VARCHAR2(18)
 EDITIONABLE                                                                      VARCHAR2(1)
 ORACLE_MAINTAINED                                                                VARCHAR2(1)
 APPLICATION                                                                      VARCHAR2(1)
 DEFAULT_COLLATION                                                                VARCHAR2(100)
 DUPLICATED                                                                       VARCHAR2(1)
 SHARDED                                                                          VARCHAR2(1)
 CREATED_APPID                                                                    NUMBER
 CREATED_VSNID                                                                    NUMBER
 MODIFIED_APPID                                                                   NUMBER
 MODIFIED_VSNID                                                                   NUMBER
 REC_ID                                                                  NOT NULL NUMBER(19)

SQL> desc t3
 Name                                                                    Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------- -------- ------------------------------------------------
 OWNER                                                                            VARCHAR2(128)
 OBJECT_NAME                                                                      VARCHAR2(128)
 PROCEDURE_NAME                                                                   VARCHAR2(128)
 OBJECT_ID                                                                        NUMBER
 SUBPROGRAM_ID                                                                    NUMBER
 OVERLOAD                                                                         VARCHAR2(40)
 OBJECT_TYPE                                                                      VARCHAR2(13)
 AGGREGATE                                                                        VARCHAR2(3)
 PIPELINED                                                                        VARCHAR2(3)
 IMPLTYPEOWNER                                                                    VARCHAR2(128)
 IMPLTYPENAME                                                                     VARCHAR2(128)
 PARALLEL                                                                         VARCHAR2(3)
 INTERFACE                                                                        VARCHAR2(3)
 DETERMINISTIC                                                                    VARCHAR2(3)
 AUTHID                                                                           VARCHAR2(12)
 RESULT_CACHE                                                                     VARCHAR2(3)
 ORIGIN_CON_ID                                                                    NUMBER
 POLYMORPHIC                                                                      VARCHAR2(5)
 REC_ID                                                                  NOT NULL NUMBER(19)

SQL>
```

Note that I've not used DROP COLUMN because that's incredibly expensive. Generally better to just go with SET UNUSED, and I've thrown in an  MOVE ONLINE at the end because all those updates could make a mess of your table row structure.